# "address not from malloc()" error using electric fence

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, electric-fence

I've been writing a test case program to demonstrate a problem with a larger program of mine,
and the test case has a bug that the original program does not.

Here's the header file:

```
// compiled with g++ -I/usr/local/bin/boost_1_43_0 -Wall -std=c++0x -g test.cpp

#include <bitset>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector< std::bitset<11> > > FlagsVector;

namespace yarl
{
    namespace path
    {
        class Pathfinder;
    }

    namespace level
    {
        class LevelMap
        {
        // Member Variables
            private:
                int width, height;
                FlagsVector flags;

            public:
                boost::shared_ptr<path::Pathfinder> pathfinder;

        // Member Functions
            LevelMap(const int, const int);

            int getWidth() const {return width;}
            int getHeight() const {return height;}

            bool getFifthBit(const int x, const int y) const
            {
                return flags.at(x).at(y).test(5);
            }
        };



        class Level
        {
        // Member Variables
            public:
                LevelMap map;

        // Member Functions
            public:
                Level(const int w=50, const int h=50);
        };
    }


    namespace path
    {
        class Pathfinder
        {
        // Member Variables
            private:
                boost::shared_ptr<level::LevelMap> clientMap;

        // Member Functions
            public:
                Pathfinder() {}
                Pathfinder(level::LevelMap* cm)
                : clientMap(cm) {}

                void test() const;
        };
    }
}
```

and here's the implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
using namespace std;

namespace yarl
{
    namespace level
    {
        LevelMap::LevelMap(const int w, const int h)
        : width(w), height(h), flags(w, vector< bitset<11> >(h, bitset<11>())),
          pathfinder(new path::Pathfinder(this)) 
        {}



        Level::Level(const int w, const int h)
        : map(w,h)
        {
            map.pathfinder->test();
        }
    }



    namespace path
    {
        void Pathfinder::test() const
        {
            int width = clientMap->getWidth();
            int height = clientMap->getHeight();
            cerr << endl;
            cerr << "clientMap->width: " << width << endl; 
            cerr << "clientMap->height: " << height << endl; 
            cerr << endl;
            for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
            {
                for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
                {
                    cerr << clientMap->getFifthBit(x,y);
                }
                cerr << "***" << endl; // marker for the end of a line in the output
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    yarl::level::Level l;
    l.map.pathfinder->test();
}
```

I link this program with electric fence, and when I run it it aborts with this error:

```
ElectricFence Aborting: free(bffff434): address not from malloc().

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

backtracing from gdb shows that the illegal instruction is in the compiler-generated destructor of `Pathfinder`, which is having trouble destructing its shared_ptr.  Anyone see why that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yarl::level::Level l;
```

You instantiate an automatic `Level` variable, which, in its constructor constructs its member `pathfinder` like so:

```
pathfinder(new path::Pathfinder(this))
```

Then in the `Pathfinder` constructor, it takes the `Level` pointer that you pass in and assigns that to a `shared_ptr`.  The `shared_ptr` then takes ownership of this pointer.

This is incorrect for several reasons:

1. A `shared_ptr` should be used to manage dynamically allocated objects, not automatically allocated objects
2. If you want to use `shared_ptr`, then you should use it everywhere:  as it is now, you pass raw pointers (e.g. to the constructor of `Pathfinder`, but then store them as `shared_ptr`s.  This just opens a big can of ownership worms.
3. The correct way to assign `this` to a `shared_ptr` is to derive from `enable_shared_from_this`; note however that you cannot get a `shared_ptr` from `this` in a constructor.

When the `shared_ptr` is destroyed, it will try to delete the pointer it manages.  In this case, however, that pointer is not to a dynamically allocated object (i.e., allocated with `new`), but to an automatically allocated object (i.e., on the stack).  Hence, the error.

If you don't need something to take ownership of a resource, there is nothing wrong with using a raw pointer (or a reference, if you have that option).

Comment: Changing LevelMap's pathfinder from a shared_ptr to a raw pointer fixed the problem, thanks for your help.  As a secondary question, I use shared_ptrs a lot in my original program, in fact the raw pointer in this example is the only non-shared_ptr I use.  Would you recommend changing all other shared_ptr to references or raw pointers?

Comment: @Max:  You should use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` to manage _dynamically allocated_ objects.  Just don't use them to manage automatically allocated objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing `shared_ptr` from a pointer which is not supposed to be managed by shared_ptr. (The `this` pointer)

When the last shared_ptr's copy is destroyed this memory is free'd - when in fact it should not - the `this` is on stack in this case.

There is a reason the constructor of `shared_ptr` is explicit - it is exactly to avoid such an unnoticed conversion from regular pointer, which is not to be managed by shared_ptr, to a shared_ptr - once you pass such a pointer into shared_ptr, your program is doomed - the only way out is by deleting the pointer you have not intended to delete.

In general it is advisable to construct shared pointer with new directly - such as `ptr(new Somethings(x,y,z)` - this way you don't risk an exception leaking your allocated, but unassigned to a shared_ptr memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `Level` contains a `LevelMap` member variable. When the `Level` gets destroyed, it will also destroy its `LevelMap`.

On the other hand a pointer to this `LevelMap` member is passed to `Pathfinder`, which creates a `shared_ptr<>` from the passed pointer. This newly created `shared_ptr<>` thinks that it owns the object it points to and will try to destroy it once the `Pathfinder` gets destroyed.

So the `LevelMap` is destroyed several times.

In the example the `LevelMap` is created on the stack. Therefore the `delete` called by `shared_ptr<>` can see that the address is not from the heap and you get an error. If your real program also has this problem, but all those objects are dynamically allocated, the error will probably not be detected. You will just get silent memory corruption and weird crashes later on.

Comment: +1.  The original problem was that I had memory corruption and similar things going on, so this might help me solve that problem.  Thanks.